# Persistir una variable

Tags: javascript

Tengo un codigo en JS que tiene una varible con la idea de que guarde un valor de manera constante. El problema es que al llamar de nuevo a ese archivo la variable se resetea a undefined.

```
const rpcURL = "http://localhost:7545";
var address, key;

function init() {
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(rpcURL));
}
}
```

Como puedo solventar esto, persistiendo el valor que establezco una vez?

Comment: Tienes varias opciones: pedirla al servidor (con un `POST`), usar [`LocalStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage), ... ). Es cosa de que escogas una :-)

Comment: Perfecto usare Local ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si necesitas persistirla durante la sesión actual podrías usar [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) o durante múltiples sesiones podrías usar [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Un ejemplo con **SessionStorage**

```
// salva web3 en sessionStorage, es importante notar la función JSON.stringify, 
// estoy asumiendo que la variable web3 es un objeto, 
// sessionStorage solo guarda strings como valores, 
// por lo que hay que transformar el objeto en un string primero
sessionStorage.setItem('web3', JSON.stringify(web3));

// Para recuperar la data se usa la función getItem, pero como guardamos un objeto en forma de string, tenemos que hacer el camino inverso
let web3 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('web3'));
```

por lo que tu código quedaría algo así:

```
const rpcURL = "http://localhost:7545";
var address, key;

function init() {
  let web3 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('web3'));
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(rpcURL));
  }
  sessionStorage.setItem('web3', JSON.stringify(web3));
}
```

las funciones de LocalStorage son similares